# How can I enable VIM for mac in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, vim

I just got Visual Studio for my Mac. Although in Beta, it seems nice. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out where VIM could be. I've searched the marketplace, but cannot load any file or extension into the IDE to enable VIM. I've checked the preferences in keyboard behavior, but nothing.

Does this IDE really not have one of the most essential tools?

Answer (score 23):

Use [VsVim](https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim) with Visual Studio for Mac 8.4 or newer.

**Original Answer**

Shameless plug - Use my plugin :) https://github.com/nosami/XSVim/releases

It's now available in the Visual Studio for Mac extension gallery (under IDE extensions)

[image: Visual Studio for Mac extension gallery]

You can usually find a more recent version on the github releases page than in the VS for Mac addin gallery.

Comment: Hey @jasoni, I'm currently using your plugin, is there anyway I can modify the key bindings? (for example, mapping `esc` to `caps lock`)

Comment: @prtdomingo: I use karabiner-elements for this purpose to remap caps-lock to escape system-wide

Comment: @jasoni Hey Jason, what's the key binding to enter the command mode? So I can do stuff like :wq and other commands. : doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: Why isn't ctrl-d page-down by the way?

Comment: @Sung see https://github.com/nosami/XSVim#why-dont-the-control-keys-work

Comment: Restart VS after installing

Comment: @Gerry You don't need to restart VS. You do need to close any tabs that are open and reopen them though.

Comment: It [looks like](https://github.com/nosami/XSVim/issues/252#issuecomment-538993082) the XSVim plugin [may be moving to VsVim](https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/pull/2733) due to a new editor in Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: @JohnCummings Yes. I am leading that effort :) See here if you want to use VsVim today on Mac https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/pull/2733#issuecomment-538998555

Comment: I do not see Vim under Gallery -> IDE Extensions. I am running Visual Studio 2019 for Mac

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio for Mac is *not* a direct port of Visual Studio for Windows. It's essentially an alpha-level rebranding (with a lot of work put into it but still) of another IDE called Xamarin Studio, itself essentially a rebranding of MonoDevelop.

As such, you shouldn't expect *any* compatibility with other tools in the Visual Studio ecosystem for the time being.

However, you can set up MacVim as an external tool if you *really* want, but you won't get any kind of integration per se:

[image: external tool]

Comment: Worthy of note - the previous Xamarin for mac had a Vim keybinding extension, but it did not work very well - in fact it was horribly poor last time I tried.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was downloading VsVim addin as `*.mpack` file from this page: https://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/403. In my case the file was named `Vim.Mac.VsVim-2.8.0.7.mpack`.

After downloading the file, I opened Visual Studio for Mac, selected `Visual Studio` - `Extensions` from the menu to open the `Extension Manager` pop-up window, clicked `Install from file...` button and selected the downloaded `*.mpack` file.

Needed to restart Visual Studio to get the extension to work.

This was done in Visual Studio for Mac 8.7.8.

Answer (score 2):

After last VisualStudio update (8.1.3 - a new Editor is in place) Vim doesn't work anymore.

At least for now, you need to mark a setting in Visual Studio that forces use of the old editor, as [described in the extension's README here](https://github.com/nosami/XSVim#81-new-editor).

From that page:

[image: directions of how to choose the old editor pane in Visual Studio]

Comment: Okay, so went ahead and made the issue you found with the new VS editor and [the extension suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43946720/1028230) into an answer *with a solution*. Before there was a solution, though, keep in mind that this was probably, best case, just a comment on that previous answer. Either way, thanks for the info and heads up, and hope this solution helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use VsVim. Also, for those who find this via google, the workaround steps are:

Uninstall the broken VsVim extension and restart Visual Studio for Mac.

1. [Download](https://addins.monodevelop.com/Stable/Mac/8.5/Vim.Mac.VsVim-2.8.0.5.mpack via your browser)
2. In VsMac, go to the Extensions pane and click Install From File. Navigate to your Downloads folder and select the .mpack file you downloaded.
3. For some reason the extension doesn't work right away. You need to restart Visual Studio for Mac.

Reference: [link](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/VsVim/VsVim/2813/612299982)